# The algebra of invariants of a binary cubic form

Tags: invariant-theory

How to find the algebra of invariants of a binary cubic form

${a_{\overset{\,}{0}}}x^3+3{a_{\overset{\,}{1}}}x^2y+3{a_{\overset{\,}{2}}}xy^2+{a_{\overset{\,}{3}}}y^3$

The algebra of invariants

$I=4\left({a_{\overset{\,}{0}}}{a_{\overset{\,}{2}}}-{a_{\overset{\,}{1}}}\!^2\right)\left({a_{\overset{\,}{1}}}{a_{\overset{\,}{3}}}-{a_{\overset{\,}{2}}}\!^2\right)-\left({a_{\overset{\,}{0}}}{a_{\overset{\,}{3}}}-{a_{\overset{\,}{1}}}{a_{\overset{\,}{2}}}\right)^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cubic equation ${\alpha_{\overset{\,}{0}}}t^3+{\alpha_{\overset{\,}{1}}}t^2+{\alpha_{\overset{\,}{2}}}t+{\alpha_{\overset{\,}{3}}}=0$ and its **Discriminant**:

$$\Delta_{(3)}=
\dfrac{4}{3}\left(3{\alpha_{\overset{\,}{0}}}{\alpha_{\overset{\,}{2}}}-{\alpha_{\overset{\,}{1}}}\!^2\right)\left(3{\alpha_{\overset{\,}{1}}}{\alpha_{\overset{\,}{3}}}-{\alpha_{\overset{\,}{2}}}\!^2\right)-\dfrac{1}{3}\left(9{\alpha_{\overset{\,}{0}}}{\alpha_{\overset{\,}{3}}}-{\alpha_{\overset{\,}{1}}}{\alpha_{\overset{\,}{2}}}\right)^2$$

Take
\begin{align*}
\left\{
\begin{split}
\alpha_{\overset{\,}{0}}&=a_{\overset{\,}{0}}\\
\alpha_{\overset{\,}{1}}&=3a_{\overset{\,}{1}}\\
\alpha_{\overset{\,}{2}}&=3a_{\overset{\,}{2}}\\
\alpha_{\overset{\,}{3}}&=a_{\overset{\,}{3}}\\
\end{split}
\right.
\end{align*}
Then you can get your answer.

(For the **Discriminant** of cubic equation, 
you can refer to some textbooks on polynomial)